# RegEx - phishing attempts in HTML

Tags: regex, url, href, pcre

I need ur help :(
What I want:
Match string if **url.text** AND **url.href** both contains URL, which are not equal (without protocol and subdomains).

It should work like this:

```
<a href="http://www.test1.net/dir1/index.html" target="_blank">test1.net/admin</a> <-- NOT MATCH
<a href="https://test2.com">THIS SITE</a> <-- NOT MATCH
<a href="https://subdomain.test3.org">test2.org</a> <-- MATCH
<a href="http://www2.test4.com" target="_blank">https://global.test4.com/index.html</a> <-- NOT MATCH
<a href="http://eu.test5.com">https://evil.com/eu.test5.com/</a> <-- MATCH
<a href="http://eu.site6.com/index.html" target="_blank">https: // eu. evil. com</a> <-- MATCH
<a href="https://site7.com/">http://www.site7.com/123/test</a> <-- NOT MATCH
```

I started write something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/CQJKOM/4), but I had a problem with my code doing the opposite.
Help me figure out how to make what I want.

Comment: [Regex is not the best fit to use on HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/479156). Can't you use an HTML parser instead?

Comment: I can help with the regex. But you'd have to explain what this means `I had a problem with my code doing the opposite`. Show some specific examples of what you _DO_ and _DO NOT_ want to match and _WHY_

Comment: @Ivar No, I can't use anything except RegEx :(

Comment: @sin The code which I shared marks strings if url.text and url.href are equal. I don't need this. I need to mark unequal things as I wrote in 'code' section above.

Comment: @refrigerator - I actually requested some exact examples _with_ explanations since seeing your examples have contradictions. And, although we want to help, nobody wants to waste their time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original expression is pretty well-designed, yet I would have used some statements such as:

```
(?!.*\1.*)
```

or:

```
(?!((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?(?:[^"\/]*\.)?(\1)).*)
```

within, to bypass the same domain in the `url.text`, maybe with some expression similar to:

```
(?i)<a\s+href="(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?(?:[^"\/]*\.)?([a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]{2,6})(\/[^"]*)?"[^>]*>(?!.*\1.*)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?(?:[^"\/]*\.)?([a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]{2,6})(\/[^"]*)?.*?<\/a>
```

or probably and more accurately with:

```
(?i)<a\s+href="(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?(?:[^"\/]*\.)?([a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]{2,6})(\/[^"]*)?"[^>]*>(?!((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?(?:[^"\/]*\.)?(\1)).*)(?:https?:\s*\/\/\s*)?(?:\s*w{3}\.\s*)?(?:[^"\/]*\.\s*)?([a-z0-9_-]+\s*\.\s*[a-z0-9_-]{2,6}\s*)(\/[^"]*)?.*?<\/a>
```

which you'd most likely want to modify, and change the boundaries. For instance, you can add `\s*` anywhere you'd want to allow some spaces, or maybe with a double-bounded quantifier `\s{0,5}`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nCqdXI/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/I3GWqK/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/I3GWqK/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Awesome! But third match doesn't work correctly. You're delete spaces between words in url.text, but I need with them.  
[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fZi1HH/2)